# Old wiring to new light fan

Tags: wiring, old-house

I have 6 wires coming out 2 black ones connected with a white one 2 white ones connected and a free standing black one the new light and fan has a white and red wire what do I do

Comment: Please post a picture. And state what was there before, and how it was connected?

Answer (score 3):

Based solely on your text description, I'd say the two-black-one-white bundle are power coming in and out to other fixtures through the black wires and the white is one wire of a switch loop. The single black wire is the other end of the switch loop. And the two-whites bundle is the neutral to the rest of the fixtures.

I would test this by finding and turning off the switch, then checking that none of the three bundles are touching each other or the junction box (if there is one). Then turn power on to the circuit and use a voltage meter to check if voltage exists across the two-black-one-white bundle and the two-white bundle. Power should also be available on the single black to the two-white bundle when the switch is on, and not available when the switch is off.

If this test is completely accurate, then you could turn off power and decide how you want to control the fan:

A. Control the fan on/off with the switch: Wire the fan red wire to the single black wire, and the fan white wire to the two-white bundle. The fan should now start when the switch is turned on and remain at the speed it is set at.

B. Control the fan with the fan's pull chain: Wire the fan red to the two-black-one-white bundle. Cap the single black with a wire nut. The fan will have power all the time and be controlled by its pull chain. The switch will do nothing.

Note that setup B will allow adding a light kit later which can be wired between the single black and the two-white neutral bundle. The switch can control the light and the fan pull chain can control the fan.

One other thing: if the junction box is not a fan-rated box, you'll need to replace the box with a proper fan-rated junction box. Otherwise the fan will eventually tear the junction box off the ceiling and fall in a possible shower of sparks and hurt people.